# Interleave List of Lists in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, fold, interleave

I was wondering how could I write a function in Haskell that interleaves a list of lists into a single lists, for example, if I had a function called

`interleavelists :: [[a]] ->  [a]`

it should be able to interleave the elements.

Example: `[[1,2,3] [4,5,6] [7,8]] --> [1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6]`.

The lists can be both finite or infinite... Can I use `foldr`?

Comment: Related: [Merging two lists in Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3938438/2157640)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The quickest way to write it is to use [`transpose`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.6.0.0/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3atranspose) from `Data.List`.

```
import Data.List

interleavelists :: [[a]] -> [a]
interleavelists = concat . transpose
```

`transpose` picks the first element of each non-empty list of its argument, putting them into one list, and after that, `transpose`s the list of `tail`s of the argument's elements. `concat`enating the lists of `transpose`'s result interleaves the lists as desired. It works if some element lists are infinite, but if the list of lists itself has infinitely many elements, it of course never gets past the list of `head`s. But handling that case is problematic anyway.

Using `foldr` to interleave the lists is not trivial. Suppose you had

```
interleavelists xss = foldr something zero xss
```

`interleavelists []` should probably produce `[]`, so that'd be the `zero` value. And

```
interleavelists [xs] = xs
```

seems natural, so

```
something xs [] = xs
```

But what if the second argument isn't `[]`? Then you want to insert the elements of the first argument of `something` at varying distances into the second argument. But at which distances? If all lists have the same length, the distances for each list are constant, then you could pass the distance as a further parameter,

```
interleavelists = snd . foldr insertAtDistance (0, [])
  where
    insertAtDistance xs (d, ys) = (d+1, helper d xs ys)
    helper _ [] ws = ws
    helper k (b:bs) cs = b : us ++ helper k bs vs
      where
        (us,vs) = splitAt k cs
```

That isn't very pretty, and if the lists are not all the same length will produce what probably isn't the desired output. But if the lists all have the same length, it does the job.

Answer (score 5):

Simple recursive version:

```
inter :: [[a]] -> [a]
inter [] = []
inter xs = inter2 (filter (\x -> not (null x)) xs)
   where inter2 xs = map head xs ++ inter (map tail xs)
```

Now, about foldr...

Answer (score 5):

The "standard" (or perhaps, famous) way of interleaving lists, back in the jolly days of SICP (and later, Reasoned Scheme), was

```
infixr 5 ++/

[]     ++/ ys = ys
(x:xs) ++/ ys = x:(ys ++/ xs)
```

It can be used with `foldr`,

```
*Main> foldr (++/) [] [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8]]
[1,4,2,7,3,5,8,6]
```

This obviously does not produce the result in the order you wanted, but it will OTOH work OK when the input list of lists is infinite. I don't think there is a way to satisfy both requirements at the same time, as we have no way of knowing whether an input list will be infinite or not.

The above results are what the function `insertAtDistance` from [Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14186594/849891) would produce, if modified to always insert at a distance of `1`, instead of `d+1`:

```
insertAtDistance xs (d, ys) = (1, helper d xs ys)
```

When defined with `d+1` it produces "flat" interleaving, whereas `foldr (++/) []` produces skewed interleaving:

```
*Main> take 20 $ foldr (++/) [] [cycle[i] | i<-[1..]]
[1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3]
```

Comment: TWIMC: be sure to search for "diagonalize Haskell list interleaving", "dovetailing", "Control.Monad.Omega", "Data.Universe.Helpers", for fuller picture. also [this](http://alaska-kamtchatka.blogspot.com/2010/06/diagonalize-now.html) seems to be a nice and interesting blog post on the matter. see also ["Cartesian product of infinite lists"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20516638/849891) or even [this answer of mine](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/97610/2909) on CS, etc.

Answer (score 2):

we could do what you want

```
testList = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8]]

interleave l = foldr' (concat [map (\x -> f x idx) l | idx <- [0..]])  
    where
        f x n = if (length(x)<=n) then Nothing else Just (x !! n)
        foldr' (x:xs) = case x of 
                         Nothing -> []
                         Just a  -> (:) a (foldr' xs)
```

As required
interleave [[1,2,3] [4,5,6] [7,8]] => [1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6]

Comment: what about `[[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8]]` ... (check out `Data.Maybe.catMaybes :: [Maybe a] -> [a]`)? What about `[[1..],[4,5,6],[7,8]]`?

Comment: You're right, and I see what you are talking about, I'll try catMaybes (I don't know this fun, thks). In fact I've already realized that my answer was incomplete (or wrong) but the answer of D. Fisher was so complete and clever that i haven't judge useful to modify mine.

Comment: `catMaybes` does the only thing it *could* conceivably do, and that is exactly is needed here. If you decide to fix it, you could make some localized changes to `foldr'`, or do a complete re-write, like `[x | Just x<- input]`. -- Both functions in Daniel Fischer's answer won't work on an infinite input list of lists - the first will get stuck on heads, but the 2nd will be completely unproductive, BTW.

Comment: correction - there are several possibilities actually - `catMaybes` could return `a`s from all `Just a`s present in a list, or just the first/last/2nd/middle/each 3rd/etc... I guess returning all is the most general thing it can do.