# Concat nesting list to string, Haskell

Tags: haskell

I do string mingling:

```
main = do
    first <- getLine
    second <- getLine
    print (zip first second)
```

result: `[('a','1'),('b','2'),('c','3')]`.

But how I can concate result to `a1b2c3`?

Comment: See this question: [Interleave List of Lists in Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186433/interleave-list-of-lists-in-haskell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do the following operations:

1) Convert the tuples inside the list to a single String which can be performed by a single `map`.

2) Concatenate the entire list

```
Prelude> let a = [('a','1'),('b','2'),('c','3')]
Prelude> let b = map (\(x,y) -> x : [y]) a
Prelude> b
["a1","b2","c3"]
Prelude> concat b
"a1b2c3"
Prelude> Prelude.foldl1' (++) b -- instead of concat you can do fold
"a1b2c3"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this in one handy line

```
let a = [('a','1'),('b','2'),('c','3')]
uncurry ((. return) . (:)) =<< a
```

Answer (score 1):

If I may add yet another (unnecessary) answer, just to show in how many (crazy) ways Haskell lets you think and solve a problem :)

```
Prelude Data.List> let input = [('a','1'),('b','2'),('c','3')]
Prelude Data.List> let (l1,l2) = unzip input
Prelude Data.List> let alt_stream s1 s2 = head s1:head s2:alt_stream (tail s1) (tail s2)
Prelude Data.List> take (length l1 * 2) $ alt_stream (cycle l1) (cycle l2)
"a1b2c3"
```