# Shuffle together two lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm just learning Haskell and I would like to make a "shuffle" function that shuffles together two lists, alternating until one runs out. So, `shuffle "abc" "defgh"` would return `"adbecfgh"`. Or `shuffle "abc" ""` returns `"abc"`.

So far I have:

```
shuffle xs ys = concatMap (\(x,y) -> [x,y]) (zip xs ys)
```

The problem is that it's only shuffling the lists for the length of the shortest list and not including the rest of the longer list. So `shuffle "abc" "defgh"` returns `"adbecf"` rather than `"adbecfgh"`.

Can anyone help me find a better approach to this?

Comment: Also [interleave list of lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186433/interleave-list-of-lists-in-haskell) is similar, yet a bit more general.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could simply provide a pointwise definition:

```
shuffle :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
shuffle [] ys = ys
shuffle xs [] = xs
shuffle (x:xs) (y:ys) = x : y : shuffle xs ys
```

Every `zip*` method in `Prelude` or `Data.List` won't work, as they will take only the length of the shorter list.

Answer (score 7):

Another, slightly shorter, way to do it pointwise, as Zeta suggested:

```
shuffle :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
shuffle [] ys = ys
shuffle (x:xs) ys = x : shuffle ys xs
```