# Haskell own function to merge two lists

Tags: list, function, haskell, merge

I need to write a function to merge two lists. Exactly like '`++`' is working.

```
let x = merge [1,2,3] [3,3,4] -- should output [1,2,3,3,3,4]
```

How should it be done?

Edit: solution is

```
merge :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge []     ys = ys
merge (x:xs) ys = x : (merge xs ys)
```

Comment: maybe this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3938449/1423473

Comment: @erthalion No, that's an unsorted interpolation. This merge sorts or concatenates, and I think they're asking for concatenation.

Comment: erthalion, this is not what I am looking for as chunks said.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this.

```
merge :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge pred xs []         = xs
merge pred [] ys         = ys
merge pred (x:xs) (y:ys) =
  case pred x y of
    True  -> x: merge pred xs (y:ys)
    False -> y: merge pred (x:xs) ys

(++) xs ys = merge (\x y -> compare x y == LT) xs ys
```

Or, if you just need to repeat the functionality of (++), you can look up it's definition with [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%2B%2B) which eventually leads you to the [source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#%2B%2B)

```
(++) []     ys = ys
(++) (x:xs) ys = x : xs ++ ys
```