# Merging two lists in the order of each elements in two lists

Tags: python, list

I looked at the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938438/merging-two-lists-in-haskell). I wanted to do the same in Python.

> List a=[ 1,2,3 none, none] list b=[4,5,3] Output=[1,4,2,5,3,3]

```
z = [ x for x in a if x != None ] + b
```

This does not work. I want the z to be [1,4,2,5,3,3]

Comment: What are the constraints on the positions of the `None`s?  And how do they influence the output?  e.g. what if the first element of `a` was `None`?  What output would you want then?

Comment: @ajcr - Agreed it is kind of duplicate but the other question did not have the None condition

Comment: I agree it's a fine line - happy to reopen if you feel that those answers aren't directly applicable to your case here (someone else had suggested that duplicate first).

Comment: @ajcr -- after cleaning up the duplicate issue, I agree that this is a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks guys. I totally agree and it looks like it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from itertools import chain
list(chain.from_iterable(zip([1, 2, 3, None, None], [4, 5, 6])))
```

`zip(a, b)` as mentioned above will create a list of tuples, and `chain.from_iterable` will flatten the list, discarding `None`s

Comment: please explain your answer so OP understands

Comment: @TomStudee tools for iterators: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to `chain` the lists after `zip`ing them together and removing `None` ...

```
from itertools import chain, izip_longest
with_none = chain.from_iterable(izip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=None)]
without_none = [x for x in with_none if x is not None]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip(a, b)` followed by flattening of list:

```
>>> [item for subtuple in zip(a, b) for item in subtuple]
[1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 3]
```

Comment: all these people doing some weird itertools stuff, quite unnecessary. +1 for plain simplicity

Comment: I personally find itertools to be much more simple than nested list-comprehensions -- But I suppose it's what you're used to...

Comment: @mgilson Yup :) Still not used to `itertools` in Python :( Never found the use till now in 6 months since I started using Python in production :)

Comment: @RohitJain -- That's a good question . . .